# Universal Windows App disable Webview to cache all JSON Documents

Tags: c#, caching, webview, win-universal-app

I am developing an UWP-App where a webview hosts a javascript application. I have much traffic of JSON documents to a database and back. However the Webview caches all the documents, which needs during the runtime extremly much RAM (up to 2GB on my machine). It also saves all the documents as textdata in a local folder. Is it possible to avoid that? I already set the `Frame.CacheSize = -1`, I also run `WebView.ClearTemporaryWebDataAsync()` in some intervals. I have no idea what I can do furthermore and the www isn't that helpfull...

Kind regards